# How would you define a Proxy Type?

Tags: c#, types, definition

I understand them conceptually, but am having a  hard time coming up with a plain English definition for them.

This is the closest fitting I think that I've come up with so far:

> Proxy Types are representations of data models that are defined elsewhere.

Comment: How about the [Proxy Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternProxy.aspx)

Comment: If you're down voting the question, I'd appreciate a suggestion as to why? Please help me make it a better question instead of just down voting. This is actually a sound question I believe.

Comment: @DavinTryon Thanks, that seems like it might be close -- although it seems to actually represent more of the Proxy itself and not the Types the Proxy might use.

Comment: That I know in Programming when we say Proxy, we refer to the Proxy Pattern. If you want to say in words more or less what it is check here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern. The sentence "A proxy, in its most general form, is a class functioning as an interface to something else." I think boils down the concept of proxy.

Comment: @Dzyann That makes more sense to me actually and you made it click for me just now. Thanks for that. Could you make that the answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That I know in Programming when we say Proxy, we refer to the Proxy Pattern.

If you want to say in words more or less what it is check here: [ProxyPattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).

The sentence "A proxy, in its most general form, is a class functioning as an interface to something else." I think boils down the concept of proxy